# dont give .o file in makefile

Tags: c++, file, makefile

> hi this is my make file for a project but after making this its give
> me [given error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgbg.png)
> four of my files i think they do not compile and i dont khnow why?
> why dosent it give me .o files

```
CC=g++
STD=-std=c++11 -Wall -pedanticCF=$(STD)
BUILD_DIR=build

all: $(BUILD_DIR) myserver.out

(BUILD_DIR)/response.o: utils/response.cpp utils/response.hpp utils/include.hpp
    $(CC) $(CF) -c utils/response.cpp -o $(BUILD_DIR)/response.o

$(BUILD_DIR)/request.o: utils/request.cpp utils/request.hpp utils/include.hpp utils/utilities.hpp
    $(CC) $(CF) -c utils/request.cpp -o $(BUILD_DIR)/request.o

$(BUILD_DIR)/utilities.o: utils/utilities.cpp utils/utilities.hpp
    $(CC) $(CF) -c utils/utilities.cpp -o $(BUILD_DIR)/utilities.o

$(BUILD_DIR)/server.o: server/server.cpp server/server.hpp server/route.hpp utils/utilities.hpp utils/response.hpp utils/request.hpp utils/include.hpp utils/template_parser.hpp utils/template_parser.cpp
    $(CC) $(CF) -c server/server.cpp -o $(BUILD_DIR)/server.o

$(BUILD_DIR)/route.o: server/route.cpp server/route.hpp utils/utilities.hpp utils/response.hpp utils/request.hpp utils/include.hpp
    $(CC) $(CF) -c server/route.cpp -o $(BUILD_DIR)/route.o

Driver.o: Driver.cpp Driver.h User.h Passenger.h
    $(CC) $(CF) -c Driver.cpp -o template_parser.o

handlers.o: handlers.cpp handlers.hpp User.h Passenger.h Driver.h server/server.hpp Location.h
    $(CC) $(CF) -c handlers.cpp -o handlers.o

Location.o: Location.cpp Location.h
    $(CC) $(CF) -c Location.cpp -o Location.o

Passenger.o: Passenger.cpp Passenger.h User.h Trip.h
    $(CC) $(CF) -c Passenger.cpp -o Passenger.o

Trip.o: Trip.cpp Trip.h Passenger.h Location.h
    $(CC) $(CF) -c Trip.cpp -o Trip.o

User.o: User.cpp User.h
    $(CC) $(CF) -c User.cpp -o User.o

Server_t.o: Server_t.cpp Server_t.hpp User.h Passenger.h Driver.h server/server.hpp Location.h utils/request.hpp utils/response.hpp
    $(CC) $(CF) -c Server_t.cpp -o Server_t.o

MyServer.o: MyServer.cpp MyServer.hpp server/server.hpp
    $(CC) $(CF) -c MyServer.cpp -o MyServer.o

main.o: main.cpp Server_t.h Location.h handlers.hpp MyServer.hpp
    $(CC) $(CF) -c main.cpp -o main.o


myserver.out: MyServer.o main.o handlers.o $(BUILD_DIR)/response.o $(BUILD_DIR)/request.o $(BUILD_DIR)/utilities.o $(BUILD_DIR)/server.o $(BUILD_DIR)/route.o $(BUILD_DIR)/template_parser.o
    $(CC) $(CF) Server_t.o User.o Trip.o Passenger.o Location.o MyServer.o main.o handlers.o $(BUILD_DIR)/response.o $(BUILD_DIR)/request.o $(BUILD_DIR)/utilities.o $(BUILD_DIR)/server.o $(BUILD_DIR)/route.o $(BUILD_DIR)/template_parser.o  -o myserver.out

clean:
    rm -r *.o *.out
```

**i dont know what is this problem
thanks for your help.**
the picture i add its my main problem

Comment: `Server_t.o`, `User.o`, ect. are not listed as dependencies of `myserver.out` so make assumes you can build `myserver.out` without them, but the command can only work, if those files are present...

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72629406/edit) your question to show the error messages(s) from `make` as text verbatim.  Having said that, none of `Server_t.o`, `User.o`, `Trip.o`, `Passenger.o` or `Location.o` are specified as dependencies of `myserver.out` .

Comment: You didn't tell `make` that it's supposed to make Server_t.o before it makes myserver.out